# Help with computing a limit in two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $h:S^1\to S^1$ be a diffeomorphism and let $H:D^2 \to D^2$ be the map $(r,\theta) \mapsto (r, h(\theta))$. I'm trying to prove that $H$ is not differentiable and therefore not smooth at $(0,0)$ (in polar coordinates). With [this expression for derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) I have the following:

$J_H = (\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & h'(\theta)\end{array})$ and

$$ \lim_{(\varepsilon, \delta) \to (0,0)} { H(\varepsilon, \delta) - H(0,0) - J_H (0,0) \cdot (\varepsilon, \delta)\over \|(\varepsilon, \delta) \|} = 
\lim_{(\varepsilon, \delta) \to (0,0)} {(0, h(\delta) - h(0) - h'(0)\cdot \delta)\over \|(\varepsilon, \delta) \|} = ?$$

For multivariable limits, is it allowed to tend epsilon to zero first and then compute 
$$ (0,{ \lim_{(0, \delta) \to (0,0)}h(\delta) - h(0) - h'(0)\cdot \delta)\over \|(0, \delta) \|} = (0,0)$$

? How can limits in two dimensions be defined at all if one can do $\lim_{(\varepsilon, 2\delta) \to (0,0)} $ etc. and get different results for same expresssions? You may asssume $h$ is not a rotation or reflection.

Comment: If $h$ is a rotation, then $H$ is one too, and hence differentiable everywhere. You should explicitly exclude these (and reflections composed with rotations).

Comment: But even if I exclude these cases the limit expression is the same?

Answer (score 1):

> For multivariable limits, is it allowed to tend epsilon to zero first and then ...

No. If you do that, you get the limit along a coordinate axis.

> I have the following: $J_H = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & h'(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$

Using polar coordinates to determine smoothness at $(0,0)$ is a bad idea, as the coordinate system itself is not smooth there. Also, think of the $\varepsilon $ and $\delta$ in your proof: do they represent the values of coordinates $r$ and $\theta$, or of $x$ and $y$? (Regardless of your answer, the computations are wrong.)

An aside: it's better to use `\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & h'(\theta) \end{pmatrix}` which is explicitly meant for matrices, and provides parentheses.

Here is my approach. Suppose that $H$ is a differentiable map of the unit ball $B\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $H(tx)=tH(x)$ for all $x\in B$ and all $0\le t<1$. (This is a more general setup than in your problem.) Let $A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be the derivative of $H$ at the origin ($A$ is a linear map). The definition of derivative implies that for all $x\in B$
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{H(tx)-A(tx)}{t}=0$$ 
But $H(tx)-A(tx)=t(H(x)-A(x))$.  Thus, $H(x)=A(x)$. $\quad \Box$

In other words, a differentiable map that is homogeneous of degree $1$ must be linear.

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer. Which book did you learn all this from, e.g. that a diff'able map homogenous of degree 1 must be linear etc? Could you recommend me that book?

Comment: Epsilon and delta in my question are the radius $r$ and the angle $\theta$. Now I will have to figure out which part of my computations is wrong because even though I am grateful and excited to learn your way of doing things I also want to be able to do them my way.

Comment: But why is $H(tx) = tH(x)$ a more general setup if it does not hold for my $H$? Also, if $H'(x) = A(x)$, shouldn't the limit be ${H(tx) \over t} - A(tx)$?